# AsciiDoc: how can I get the author's name in the output document?

Tags: markup-languages

This is the beginning of an AsciiDoc document, where the author is specified:

```
= Writing Documentation using AsciiDoc
Tom White <twhite@mymail.com>
v2.0, 2020-11-06
:toc:
```

The author name is accepted by the AsciiDoc processor, i.e. no error is produced, but it is not shown in the output document.

How is it possible to make the author's name visible?

Comment: One of the more tech-oriented SEs might help a bit more

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b - Thank you, I just wrote this question on StackOverflow.